# PHP PDO::lastInsertId() returns 0

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Thanks in advance for reading this, I couldn't find an answer that solved my problem... I don't understand what I'm doing differently than the tutorials/suggestions I found:

**SQL Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `LastInsertID` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` char(150) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

**PHP File**

```
<?php

// Connect to database
$user = "foo";
$pswd = "bar";

$db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pswd );
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// Prepare request
$rq = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO `LastInsertID` VALUES(NULL,:name,:email)');

// Begin and commit request
$db->beginTransaction();
$values = array('name'=>'Foo','email'=>'bar@baz.com');
$rq->execute($values);
$db->commit();

// Echo last ID
echo $db->lastInsertId();

?>
```

This returns 0 when it should return 6. Where is the problem?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php#85129

Comment: @Pekka웃 Stupid me, I didn't read the sentence before the code example...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use `$db->lastInsertId()` before you commit if you are in a transaction. Even if you rollback a transaction, the id is "used" or skipped, which is why you should not depend on IDs to be sequential.

Comment: Thanks; this returns the right ID :) But what if I execute several prepared requests in different tables without commit, will it be updated correctly after each request?

Comment: Yes, you can do many queries and get the id for each within a transaction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I'll mark you as the answer asa SO lets me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
INSERT INTO `LastInsertID` (name, email) VALUES(:name,:email)
```

instead

```
INSERT INTO `LastInsertID` VALUES(NULL,:name,:email)
```

I have removed the `NULL`.

Comment: That doesn't change the behaviour

Comment: @Pekka웃 Ok I am in doubt here . If for `Id` which is unique and auto increment is set as `NULL` will not affect?

Comment: if you specify `NULL`, the auto increment will fill in the correct value. (The way you propose isn't wrong either - it just doesn't solve the OP's problem, which has to do with commits, see Mike's answer)