# PHP PDO::lastInsertId returns 0

Tags: php, pdo, last-insert-id

I have a similar problems that you can find in others questions, but answers were not sufficient :
[this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894155/php-pdolastinsertid-returns-0)

In my case the insert is right but I don't manage to get the ID. it returns 0 all the times.
Why ?

**Script.php**

```
$src_db_conn = database_connection( SRC_DB_HOST , SRC_DB_NAME, SRC_DB_USERNAME, SRC_DB_PASSWORD );
$target_db_conn = database_connection( TARGET_DB_HOST , TARGET_DB_NAME, TARGET_DB_USERNAME, TARGET_DB_PASSWORD );

$sql_insert_terms = "SELECT nom_cat, slug FROM src_table ";
$result           = $src_db_conn->query($sql_insert_terms);

foreach ( $result as $row ){

    $f_wp_terms_row = array(
        'name' => $row['nom_cat'],
        'slug' => $row['slug']
    );

    $sql_insert_terms = "INSERT INTO target_table (name, slug) VALUES (:name, :slug)";
    $stmt = $target_db_conn->prepare( $sql_insert_terms );
    try {
        $target_db_conn->beginTransaction();
        $stmt->bindParam(":name", $f_wp_terms_row['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":slug", $f_wp_terms_row['slug'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        print $target_db_conn->lastInsertId();
        $target_db_conn->commit();
    } catch(PDOExecption $e) {
        $target_db_conn->rollback();
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "</br>";
    }

}
```

**database_connection php function**

```
function database_connection( $host, $dbname, $username, $password ){
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Connected successfully";
        return $conn;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
}
```

**target_table shema**

```
Nom    Type         Attributs Extra NULL
foo_id bigint(20)   UNSIGNED  A_I   No
name   varchar(200)                 No 
slug   varchar(200)                 No
```

Comment: if that column isn't AI'd, then it won't work, should this be the case.

Comment: what means "isn't AI'd" ? Auto_increment ?

Comment: AI = AUTO_INCREMENT ;-)

Comment: what is your table schema ?

Answer (score 0):

I have to bind with the column id like this :

```
print $target_db_conn->lastInsertId("foo_id");
```